# How can i call a different phone number with a single button?

Tags: ios

Im trying to have a button that when pressed will call the person that is displayed on a `UIView`. Each person has their info passed through a segue to only use a template `UIWebView` in storyboard but will show as a different person when a person from the list is clicked and displayed with their info. It works with an image, title and label but not with the buttons for the calling texting or paging as it says incompatible pointer type so how would i go about fixing this? Also how would can i get the texting feature to be able to work in this code? The calling and paging work fine for attempting to create the call but doesn't work due to the first problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = self.person.personName;
    self.personImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.person.personImage];
    self.nameLabel.text = self.person.personName;
    self.textButton = self.person.textNumber; //Warning here: incompatible pointer type from NSString to UIButton"
    self.callButton = self.person.phoneNumber; //Warning here: incompatible pointer type from NSString to UIButton?
    self.pageButton = self.person.pagingNumber; //Warning here: incompatible pointer type from NSString to UIButton

}

-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://phoneNumber"]];
}

-(IBAction)textPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"smsprompt://textNumber"]];
}

-(IBAction)pagePhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://pagingNumber"]];
}
```

Comment: Which lines give the problem? What is the full and exact error message? What are the actual types of the value involved? Put all of this info in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign an `NSString` to a `UIButton`.

1. self.callButton is a `(UIButton *)`
2. self.person.phoneNumber is a `(NSString *)`

To set the button's name, do this:

```
[self.callButton setTitle:self.person.phoneNumber
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal
];
[self.callButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(callPhone:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside
];
```

Comment: Ok yeah when i try this it changes the text of the buttons to the number and i kinda want the opposite i want the names to show but when clicked it shows the number to call

Comment: You may be missing the action:@selector(callPhone:)

Answer (score 0):

Because your button are common layout for each "user card", I would recommend passing the information relative to the button through your segue instead of the button itself:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = self.person.personName;
    self.personImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.person.personImage];
    self.nameLabel.text = self.person.personName;
    self.numberValue = self.person.textNumber; 
    self.phoneNumberValue = self.person.phoneNumber; 
    self.pagingValue = self.person.pagingNumber; 

}

-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", self.phoneNumberValue]];
}

-(IBAction)textPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"smsprompt:%@", self.numberValue]]];
}

-(IBAction)pagePhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", self.pagingValue]];
}
```

Where `self.numberValue`, `self.phoneNumberValue`, `self.pagingValue` are `NSString`.

***EDIT: simple example for passing value***

In the following example, I show you how to pass your values through your controllers, notice that I didn't focus on your "layout" but really just on your issue by including my recommendation (passing data instead of button itself). I also voluntary deleted non-pertinent method for this example (`didReceiveMemoryWarning`, `initWithNibName`, etc..).

Hope it will help

UITableViewController.m:

```
@implementation _4601253ViewController {
    UITableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *phoneNumberList;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    /* Init objects */
    phoneNumberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"232323", @"434445", @"367843", @"938472", nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

#pragma mark - UITableView DataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [phoneNumberList count];;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 20)];
    label.text = @"phone number:";

    UILabel *phoneNumberValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 10, 100, 20)];
    phoneNumberValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+262692 %@", [phoneNumberList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    phoneNumberValue.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10];

    [cell addSubview:phoneNumberValue];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ReceiverViewController *rvc = [[ReceiverViewController alloc] init];
    rvc.phoneNumberValue = [phoneNumberList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self presentViewController:rvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
}
```

Your receiving UIViewController.m:

```
@implementation ReceiverViewController

@synthesize phoneNumberValue = _phoneNumberValue;    // In your .h you should define this property

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 250, 30)];
    [button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"call me: +262692 %@", _phoneNumberValue] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Your method here
}
```

Comment: Ok so in the viewController.h for it would i still have

    'property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *phoneNumberValue;
    property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *numberValue;
    property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *pagingValue;

Or

    property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *phoneNumberValue;
    property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *numberValue;
    property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *pagingValue;'

Comment: No, in your `view controller` you should create 3 new `NSString` called "numberValue", "phoneNumberValue" and "pagingValue" (see the last quote of my post). The NSString should not be IBOutlet, just global variable which can be set from outside (in your case by the tableViewController). So finally your scheme should be: `TableViewControllerA -> cellSelectionned -> pushViewControllerBWithPassedNSString -> InitButtonWithPassedNSStringValue`

Comment: OK when i do that though the app crashes when i click on a person in the table view due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException

Comment: @user3705631 I would need more information about your new issue, you should update your initial post

Comment: Yeah but it only crashes when i implement this new code into the system. But otherwise works so i can access the persons detail but not get the call, texting or paging to work.

Comment: @user3795631 I added a really basic example to my answer focusing on passing the values, I hope it will help you in your work

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get this to work by playing around with the code you both gave me and ended up with this.

```
[self.callButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callPhone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//call button

-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", self.person.phoneNumber]]];
```

So huge thanks on the help for this problem. Though the sms button isnt working still and any advice on fixing that would be greatly appreciated as well.